# How to use cx_freeze with vispy?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, vispy

I'm running into problems trying to freeze a vispy app.

This is the error:

```
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "console_example.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\vispy\scene\visuals.py", line 41, in __init__
    subclass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 380, in __init__
    self._font = self._font_manager.get_font(face, bold, italic)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 127, in get_font
    self._fonts[key] = TextureFont(font, self._renderer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._kernel = np.load(op.join(_data_dir, 'spatial-filters.npy'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 369, in load
    fid = open(file, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*snip*\\build\\exe.win32-3.4\\library.zip\\vispy\\io\\_data\\spatial-filters.npy'
```

I saw this and checked whether the file it references was included in library.zip. It wasn't, so I changed my cx_freeze setup.py to look like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["pyglet", "vispy"],
                     "includes": ["vispy.app.backends._pyglet"],
                     "zip_includes": [("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\vispy\\io\\_data\\spatial-filters.npy",
                                       "vispy/io/_data/spatial-filters.npy")]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name = "Test",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "Test",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("console_example.py", base=base)])
```

Now the spatial-filters.npy file from _data is inside library.zip where it's meant to be, but the error remains. What else do I need to do?

Comment: vispy probably can't load its data files from inside a zip file. You may need to put it outside the zip file and tell Python where to find it, or put the whole vispy package outside the zip file.

Comment: You're probably right but I'm not sure how to do either of the things you mention. cx_freeze replace_paths looks interesting but the docs don't say too much.

Comment: Indeed the reason is that at the moment Vispy needs a normal file, not a file in a zipfile. You can either do as Thomas suggests and put the visypy code in a subdirectory next to your exe and add that dir to sys.path in your main script. Or, you can contribute to Vispy to make it smarter with frozen apps.